# Building Tensorflow with Bazel fails (Ubuntu 18.04, Cuda 9.1)

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@asmello/how-to-install-tensorflow-cuda-9-1-into-ubuntu-18-04-b645e769f01d) to install tensorflow with Cuda 9.1, but when I run the following command ...

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

...I get this error after long minutes of compilation

```
INFO: From Compiling tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/virtual_cluster.cc:
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/common_shape_fns.h:22:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/resource_mgr.h:24,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device.h:43,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_set.h:23,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/virtual_cluster.h:21,
                 from tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/virtual_cluster.cc:16:
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h: In function 'tensorflow::TensorShape tensorflow::ShapeFromFormat(tensorflow::TensorFormat, tensorflow::int64, tensorflow::gtl::ArraySlice<long long int>, tensorflow::int64)':
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:501:45: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if (format == FORMAT_NHWC_VECT_W && dim == spatial.size() - 1) {
                                         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h:24:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/platform/logging.h:25,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/lib/core/refcount.h:22,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/platform/tensor_coding.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:24,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device.h:35,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_set.h:23,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/virtual_cluster.h:21,
                 from tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/virtual_cluster.cc:16:
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h: In instantiation of 'T tensorflow::GetTensorDim(tensorflow::gtl::ArraySlice<T>, tensorflow::TensorFormat, char) [with T = long long int; tensorflow::gtl::ArraySlice<T> = absl::Span<const long long int>]':
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:452:47:   required from here
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:420:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   CHECK(index >= 0 && index < dimension_attributes.size())

./tensorflow/core/platform/macros.h:87:47: note: in definition of macro 'TF_PREDICT_FALSE'
 #define TF_PREDICT_FALSE(x) (__builtin_expect(x, 0))
                                               ^
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:420:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CHECK'
   CHECK(index >= 0 && index < dimension_attributes.size())
   ^
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h: In instantiation of 'T tensorflow::GetFilterDim(tensorflow::gtl::ArraySlice<T>, tensorflow::FilterTensorFormat, char) [with T = long long int; tensorflow::gtl::ArraySlice<T> = absl::Span<const long long int>]':
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:461:54:   required from here
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:435:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   CHECK(index >= 0 && index < dimension_attribute.size())

./tensorflow/core/platform/macros.h:87:47: note: in definition of macro 'TF_PREDICT_FALSE'
 #define TF_PREDICT_FALSE(x) (__builtin_expect(x, 0))
                                               ^
./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:435:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CHECK'
   CHECK(index >= 0 && index < dimension_attribute.size())
   ^
ERROR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/BUILD:24:1: error while parsing .d file: /home/mounir/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mounir/d313cf0d9cbad5990e55f24fb423f009/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/_objs/python/ops/_nccl_ops_gpu/nccl_ops.pic.d (No such file or directory)
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:33:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:34:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:35:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/lib/core/status.h:23:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:29,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27:0,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:33:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h:24:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:30,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.h:23:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:24,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:30,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1904.904s, Critical Path: 126.88s
INFO: 3547 processes: 3547 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**My system setup is as follows :**

- Nvidia drivers version 390
- Ubuntu 18.04
- GPU Nvidia P400 Quadro(Compute Capability 6.1)
- Cuda 9.1
- Cudnn 7.1.3
- NCCL 2.1.15

**EDIT :**
After updating protobuf to 3.6.1 through :

```
pip install protobuf
```

the problem is still appearing :

```
ERROR: /home/mounir/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/BUILD:24:1: error while parsing .d file: /home/mounir/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mounir/84217cc82dae4826232c875306f45ef9/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/nccl/_objs/python/ops/_nccl_ops_gpu/nccl_ops.pic.d (No such file or directory)
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:33:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:34:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:35:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/lib/core/status.h:23:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:29,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/log_memory.h:19,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.h:21,
                 from ./tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.h:31,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:21:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27:0,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/kernel_def.pb.h:33:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:27,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h:24:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:30,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/op_def.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.h:23:0,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:24,
                 from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:30,
                 from tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_ops.cc:22:
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
bazel-out/k8-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1294.361s, Critical Path: 71.52s
INFO: 4743 processes: 4743 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow requires the latest version of protobuf. Is it possible that you have a version of protobuf older than 3.6.0?
Could you update protobuf version on your system to the latest (3.6.1), run `bazel clean`, reconfigure and rebuild tensorflow?

Comment: I updated protobuf using this command : **pip install protobuf**. But the same problem is still popping up. Is it due to the fact that the protobuf update happens within anaconda3 libraries ?

Comment: I installed the last version of protobuf (3.6.1) following some commands [here](https://gist.github.com/sofyanhadia/37787e5ed098c97919b8c593f0ec44d8). I cleaned bazel and I relaunched it, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I tried many versions of protobuf, including older versions and latest one 3.6.1. But, only version 3.6.0 works well.

Maybe you can try protobuf version 3.6.0, I hope it will work for you.

> Btw, you are compiling the tensorflow C++, you need to download protobuf_cpp_3.6.0.zip rather than install it use **pip install protobuf**

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.0/protobuf-cpp-3.6.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

Updating protobuf to version 3.6.1 will not make a difference to your tensorflow installation/compilation. The compilation of tensorflow is done using Bazel which downloads the source code of Protobuf (3.6.0 as of writing).

One method to use 3.6.1 to compile tensorflow is to edit the workspace.bzl file in the tensorflow/tensorflow/ directory. You will need to change the following part:

```
diff --git a/tensorflow/workspace.bzl b/tensorflow/workspace.bzl
index 8e6f414..1493789 100755
--- a/tensorflow/workspace.bzl
+++ b/tensorflow/workspace.bzl
@@ -366,11 +366,11 @@ def tf_workspace(path_prefix = "", tf_repo_name = ""):
     )

     PROTOBUF_URLS = [
-        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v3.6.0.tar.gz",
-        "https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v3.6.0.tar.gz",
+        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v3.6.1.tar.gz",
+        "https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v3.6.1.tar.gz",
     ]
-    PROTOBUF_SHA256 = "50a5753995b3142627ac55cfd496cebc418a2e575ca0236e29033c67bd5665f4"
-    PROTOBUF_STRIP_PREFIX = "protobuf-3.6.0"
+    PROTOBUF_SHA256 = "3d4e589d81b2006ca603c1ab712c9715a76227293032d05b26fca603f90b3f5b"
+    PROTOBUF_STRIP_PREFIX = "protobuf-3.6.1"

     tf_http_archive(
         name = "protobuf_archive",
```

By doing this, you are changing the version of protobuf that Bazel is using to compile Tensorflow and to generate the .pb.h files.